# Firefox doesn't init tls session

Tags: firefox, webrtc, sdp

What I want: Connect with browser by WebRTC.

What I have: Works in Chrome but not in Firefox (v69).

What I do:

Send offer sdp:

```
v=0
o=- 45635473 45635473 IN IP4 192.168.45.107
s=-
t=0 0
a=sendrecv
a=group:BUNDLE audio
a=msid-semantic:WMS *
m=audio 22790 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 8
c=IN IP4 192.168.100.249
a=candidate:2222216195 1 udp 2113937151 192.168.100.249 22790 typ host generation 0 network-cost 999
a=sendrecv
a=end-of-candidates
a=fingerprint:sha-256 12:60:3D:50:84:16:E7:CE:48:92:C2:69:FC:6B:7C:7F:5C:BA:38:9F:B4:01:C0:D9:7A:25:46:AA:78:1B:7A:C1
a=ice-options:trickle
a=ice-pwd:dqiAkA7gz+KCbmB8Fvqx/I6K
a=ice-ufrag:5555
a=mid:audio
a=ptime:20
a=rtcp:22790 IN IP4 192.168.100.249
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=setup:actpass
a=ssrc:305419896 cname:{9f920404-13ea-41d3-a713-dd7d5a2a3f8c}
a=ssrc:305419896 msid:{7c832778-1f71-4a78-ac13-2128307e7505} {105c1d78-bbf9-4ad4-a5fa-13e298818389}
```

Get answer sdp:

```
v=0
o=mozilla...THIS_IS_SDPARTA-70.0 4210281848269721021 0 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
s=-
t=0 0
a=fingerprint:sha-256 57:EF:92:15:61:E1:88:F4:D8:6C:92:C0:83:E1:A6:1D:72:40:94:CC:FC:22:35:D6:A1:DE:90:66:87:2A:3B:36
a=group:BUNDLE audio
a=ice-options:trickle
a=msid-semantic:WMS *
m=audio 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 8
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=sendrecv
a=ice-pwd:5982b9957048e05908f949e516627a62
a=ice-ufrag:56d206b1
a=mid:audio
a=msid:{6a68b1cb-a051-4183-be60-f4294b5aff3e} {954d21c7-c148-4083-b14b-e38bf53cebce}
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=setup:active
a=ssrc:1350429253 cname:{e4ad1fde-1111-4882-8b16-55155c461ba9}
```

At about:webrtc page I have some logs (It is fragment of these):

```
ICE-PEER(PC:1570470352934806 (id=105226698753 url=https://192.168.100.249/):default)/CAND-PAIR(xnNi): setting pair to state SUCCEEDED: xnNi|IP4:192.168.100.249:22790/UDP|IP4:192.168.100.249:22790/UDP(prflx|candidate:2222216195 1 udp 2113937151 192.168.100.249 22790 typ host generation 0 network-cost 999)

ICE-PEER(PC:1570470352934806 (id=105226698753 url=https://192.168.100.249/):default): no FROZEN/WAITING pairs for PC:1570470352934806 (id=105226698753 url=https://192.168.100.249/) transport-id=transport_0 - 56d206b1:5982b9957048e05908f949e516627a62

ICE(PC:1570470352934806 (id=105226698753 url=https://192.168.100.249/)): peer (PC:1570470352934806 (id=105226698753 url=https://192.168.100.249/):default) Trickle grace period is over; marking every component with only failed pairs as failed.

+++++++ END ++++++++
```

So, I got STUN request but not DTLS after it.

```
|           Remote candidate          |  ICE State  |  Nominated  |  Selected   |

|    192.168.100.249:22790/udp(host)  |  succeeded  |    false    |    false    |
```

Comment: How did you verify that there are no DTLS packets exchanged? Is it possible that your implementation rejects the DTLS client hello from Firefox?

Comment: I see packets in Wireshark. I get hello from chrome, but Firefox don't send it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Didn't catch it when I initially looked at your ICE table, but in your example above ICE had not yet finished. You have a success state, but `Nominated` and `Selected` should be true and not false.
My guess would be that your endpoint is the ICE controller and hasn't send the use-candidate attribute yet. So Firefox still waits for your endpoint to say which ICE candidate pair to use, before it can send the DTLS hello over the chosen connection.

Answer (score 0):

When SFU send offer, Add `a=ice-lite` line on SDP will fix the problem.